# Can I printf g++'s architechture

Tags: architecture, g++

I'd like to do something similar to this in g++:

```
printf("Architecture: %s", M_ARCH);
```

but I don't know how or if it's even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there doesn't appear to be anything that easy.

Specific architectures are defined such as `__amd64__` and `__i386__`, but you would have to write your own macro to check `#ifdef __amd64__` etc to define your own `M_ARCH`.

(You can check all of the existing preprocessor definitions by using `gcc -dM -E foo.c > defines`.)